# How to find low performance code in my t-sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have some nested procedures which show low performance. In order to find bottle neck I inserted into t-sql code some debug marks for measure performance of chunks of code which I suspect in low performance. This debug marks look like:

```
select @start_point = GETDATE() -- start measuring point
---
open @session_license_fee_cur -- suspected chunk of code
---
select @end_point = GETDATE()-- end measuring point
select @duration = datediff(ms, @start_point, @end_point)
select @log_info_total = 'Opening cursor license_fee (bills_supp_create_license_fee) (@class_id = ' + cast(@class_id as nvarchar) + ')';

exec bills_supp_save_calculation_log @duration, @log_info_total, @house_id, @account_id, @log_level -- procedure for creating log (simple insert into log table pes_bl_bills_calculation_log_total)
```

After running the procedures I run query from `pes_bl_bills_calculation_log_total` table to find lowest performance code. It looks like this

```
    set @session_license_fee_cur =  cursor static for 
    select activity_id
            , addendum_id
            , service_id
            , active_from
            , active_to
    from dbo.bills_supp_get_activate_license_fee_for_sessions_by_house(@active_from, @active_to, @house_id)

select @start_point = GETDATE()
---
open @session_license_fee_cur
---
select @end_point = GETDATE()
select @duration = datediff(ms, @start_point, @end_point)
select @log_info_total = 'Opening cursor license_fee (bills_supp_create_license_fee) (@class_id = ' + cast(@class_id as nvarchar) + ')';
exec bills_supp_save_calculation_log @duration, @log_info_total, @house_id, @account_id, @log_level
```

In other words open `@session_license_fee_cur` works very slowly (about 501980 ms).

I’m trying to run this chunk of code with given parameters in SQL Server Management Studio in order to look on query plan and try to optimize it. I run it like this

```
declare @active_from date = '01.03.2014'
declare @active_to date = '01.04.2014'
declare @house_id integer = 11927
        select activity_id
                , addendum_id
                , service_id
                , active_from
                , active_to
        from dbo.bills_supp_get_activate_license_fee_for_sessions_by_house(@active_from, @active_to, @house_id)
```

But it works very fast (returns 3000 records in about 0(zero) seconds).
What the difference in opening cursor in procedure

```
open @session_license_fee_cur
```

And running it in SQL Server Management Studio?

```
declare @active_from date = '01.03.2014'
declare @active_to date = '01.04.2014'
declare @house_id integer = 11927
        select activity_id
                , addendum_id
                , service_id
                , active_from
                , active_to
        from dbo.bills_supp_get_activate_license_fee_for_sessions_by_house(@active_from, @active_to, @house_id)
```

Where is my bottle neck?

Comment: The main diff is engine ill not need to handle the cursor. You can try hint that cursor using FAST_FORWARD but in general the best approach is to avoid cursors. btw use sysdatetime() instead of getdate()

Comment: Thank you Jean. It seems that I've found found problem. The subquery in function bills_supp_get_activate_license_fee_for_sessions_by_house had one full scan query which cause degradation.

But one thing I didn't get. Why this query without cursor in SQL Management Studio works about zero seconds, but in query it works more than 5 minutes.

Why such difference?

Comment: You must see the query plans generated, that can give you some clues (including about full table scans). Maybe the cursor is allocating a large amount of memory/tempdb. Try to monitor CPU, Memory and IO to see what that cursor declaration is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Find Top 5 expensive Queries from a Read IO perspective

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/DMVs/102045/

Comment: Thank you. But top 5 queries show not what I revealed by my logs. It shows me procedures which work quick enough from my logs point of view. 
Maybe I'm wrong but first two of "read expansive" queries shows me in column "Total Physical Reads" number 3811. Unfortunately I don't know is it much or not but my intuition suggests me that it's not so much. Am I right?